# Given a minimal prime $P$ in a noetherian ring, is there a maximal prime ideal chain starting at $P$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Like the title already reads:

> Given a minimal prime $P$ in a noetherian ring $R$ (of finite Krull dimension), is there a maximal prime ideal chain (hence of length $\dim(R)$) starting at $P$?

Obviously, if we have a maximal prime ideal chain starting at some prime $P$, then $P$ is necessarily minimal. But what about the other way around?

I would appreciate any kind of help, reference etc.

Comment: Please note that there are (at least) two notions of maximal. In your question you seem to be asking for a chain of maximal length, i.e., there is no longer chain. But a chain is also called maximal if it can't be refined. That is, a chain $P_0 \subset \dotsb \subset P_t$ is maximal if whenever we try to refine it by inserting a prime ideal $P_{i-1} \subset Q \subset P_i$, we must have $P_{i-1}=Q$ or $Q=P_i$. Every chain of maximal length is also maximal in this sense of refinements. But not the converse (even if there's no longer refinement, there may be some longer chain elsewhere).

Comment: In particular, for any minimal prime $P$, by Zorn's Lemma (we *are* adopting the axiom of choice, right?) there is a maximal prime ideal chain starting at $P$, in the sense that the chain can't be refined. The problem is the "hence of length $\dim(R)$", that part is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false in general. Since you tagged algebraic geometry, I will give you an geometric example.

Note that you ask whether $\dim R/P$ is the same for all minimal prime ideals. Geometrically $R/P$ corresponds to an irreducible component.

Hence you just have to construct something with irreducible components of different dimensions.

If you allow disconnected examples, you can just take the union of a line and point outside of the line, i.e. take $k[x,y]/I$ with $I=(x,y) \cdot (x-1)$

If you dont want to have disconnected examples, you can take a plane and a line, for instance $k[x,y,z]/I$ with $I=(x) \cdot (y,z)$.

---

If you want an ad-hoc example, take $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Q$. The prime ideal $\mathbb Z \times 0$ is both minimal and maximal, while there is a chain $0 \times \mathbb Q \subset p\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Q$ of other prime ideals.